# SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried to start my avd on Ubuntu 64bit 10.10, but it failed and shows the following in the log:

```
SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device
```

What can I do with that?

I tried to search for solutions and someone says it needs x11/sdl/jdk library and I installed them all but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this to work after installing:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-sdl
```

Comment: I don't see any package called 'ia322stdc++6b32
', perhaps you mean 'lib32stdc++6'?

Answer (score 33):

For Fedora 14 and 16 64bit.

Install these packages:

```
yum install glibc.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc libstdc++.i686 \
    libzip.i686 libX11.i686 libXrandr.i686 SDL.i686
```

Comment: +1 Awesome man. I tried running the emulator after the installation of each of the packages missing on my machine. After the install of libXrandr.i686, it worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fedora 17 64bit kernel 3.5.2 works perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked on Fedora 16 (3.4.2). Package libstdc doesn't exist but the others worked fine.

Answer (score 22):

I just encountered this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (Precise) and solved it by installing the 32-bit version of libsdl:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Comment: Thank you - this was the only one which worked for me - Kubuntu 64 12.04

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&  sudo apt-get update`

if unable to locate package

Answer (score 8):

Try unsetting any environment variables along the line of SDL_*, such as SDL_VIDEODRIVER. If that doesn't work, try `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Comment: Too bad, that's the extent of my knowledge of this. The latter solution worked for me on that error.

Comment: FWIW, seems like most of the other answers relate to the "first time usage" of an SDL binary; `export DISPLAY=:0` worked for me and may be relevant to others where a SSH init script changes the chosen display for X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

also works on Debian/Sid amd64 with the foreign architecture i386.

thank you to [crimeminister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498032/crimeminister)

Answer (score 3):

If working on a 64 bit linux system you should use the emulator64* commands instead of the emulator* commands without the "64" in their name.

Answer (score 2):

I get the "SDL init failure" when running the "emulator" command with a user with not enough privileges. Ex. jenkins user gets the error, but not root.

Drop to the commandline and run the emulator command with your normal user. You should get the same error.

Then switch to root and run emulator command again to see if user permissions or missing/wrong user environment variables is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Hpejakle/Android

Couple of things: Run your emulator call with strace, that'll tell you where it's going sideways...  May not necessarily allow you to fix it easily though...

It could be a number of things, the fact that your on 64 bit ubuntu tells me that there are probably missing libraries (32bit).

Check out the link and see if anyone has come up with a faq for Ubuntu 64

Good luck,

Gary

Answer (score 1):

If you, like me, by accident installed manually the SDL library downloading the package and running:

`./configure`

`make`

`sudo make install`

but then also installed it using the package administrator with

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`

Then it's possible that you have some conflicts between the libraries.
Try uninstalling the pkg version

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libsdl2-dev`

and manually `cd` in the directory where you have run `./config` and type

`sudo make uninstall`

After that you are able to reinstall from pakage(usually preferable) running

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`

Answer (score 0):

The following command

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

works on 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

also works on ubuntu 13.10

thank you to crimeminister

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Show emulator window" in Jenkins job configuration at android section.

[SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841908/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device/23079452#23079452)

["[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955837/android-emulator-did-not-appear-to-start-giving-up)