# Android - Fedora - Installing 32 bit packages

Tags: android, linux, fedora, yum

I'm trying to setup my Android Development on a Linux Fedora box by following the guide listed here, [HOWTO Setup Android Development - FedoraProject](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User%3aHpejakle/Android#Hello_Fedora).  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to run the yum command to install the 32 bit packages.  Specifically running this,

```
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```

outputs these "no package available" messages.

```
No package glibc-devel.i686 available.
No package libstdc++.i686 available.
No package zlib-devel.i686 available.
No package ncurses-devel.i686 available.
No package libX11-devel.i686 available.
No package libXrender.i686 available.
No package libXrandr.i686 available.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to install these libraries on my Fedora device?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but you haven't stated either way - are you definitely running this on a 64-bit machine? You only need to install the 32-bit support libraries on a 64-bit host. I haven't got Fedora, but I assume you can just remove the ".i686" component of the package name on 32-bit hosts.

Comment: Well using that fedora guide to android was suggested by this post which is the emulator error I get [SDL init failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841908/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device/5062725#5062725) .  "uname -m" yields i686 so you may be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, it ended up being a 32 bit system so I just needed to run the yum install command for each component without the .i686.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 24

```
dnf install compat-libstdc++-296 compat-libstdc++-33 glibc libgcc nss-softokn-freebl libstdc++ ncurses-libs zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 ant
```