# How to run Android Emulator from Shell on Ubuntu Server

Tags: android, ubuntu, server

I installed Android SDK and JDK on Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64. But when I run the AVD, I got

> error: 'SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device'

I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965679

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

but didn't work.

Should I install any desktop on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Android Emulator is a graphical application, so naturally it requires a desktop to run. Why are you running it on a server?

Comment: You may also find it useful to ask this question on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @1615903 because I wan't to uploading apk to remote server using webpage and run it.

Comment: @Todd Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: But you cannot run Android Emulator in an SSH terminal, it is a graphical application.

Comment: @1615903 oh, sorry. I just find that that should not run from SSH terminal. can it run from shell?

Answer (score 11):

Try to run emulator without GUI following these steps:

From: http://paulemtz.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-testing-in-headless-emulator.html

> Then, to run the headless emulator:

```
emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window
```

> The '-no-skin' option removes the emulator buttons such as the home and other hardware keyboard buttons.
>
> The '-no-audio' option disables the audio support.
>
> Finally, the '-no-window' option disables the emulator's graphical window display.

Note that `-avd test` would need to be modified to refer to your specific emulator image (AVD).

Comment: if it's working solution, please check it as answer to help others

Comment: hmm, i wonder if there is no windows will automate test ui ex.robotframework will able to verify or not.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot run an emulator on the Server version of Ubuntu. The Emulator requires a [GUI](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/G/Graphical_User_Interface_GUI.html). Which the Server OS does not possess.

Rather use an [Ubuntu Desktop OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Then [network your Server and Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop), get the APK and upload it.

If you still wish to use Ubuntu Server with a GUI, refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI), and repost the question with Ubuntu Server tags.

Comment: This is not true.
You can run Android Emulator on Ubuntu Server.
For example: If you add `-no-window` it's creating an emulator in headless mode which works on Ubuntu Server.