# pygame.error: No available video device

Tags: python, pygame

I have this setup:

```
 $ python -V
Python 2.7.2+
 $ python -c "import pygame; print pygame.__version__"
1.9.1release
```

When I run a pygame script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/santosh/tmp/pygameHelloWorld.py", line 8, in <module>
    windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.error: No available video device
```

I am using Ubuntu and have install pygame with apt-get. Additionally I have install all dependencies mentioned on this [pygame wiki page](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu).

Comment: Remember that pygame is built on top of the C library SDL, so you might be able to find some additional steps to try by googling for the error message "No available video device" as it relates to SDL.

Comment: Can we see some of the code in pygameHelloWorld.py prior to where you set the display mode?  Are you calling init on pygame first?

Comment: Also, the documentation for pygame.display recommends not passing in a  depth value to the set_mode function.  I don't think it would be causing your problem, but have you tried just calling pygame.display.set_mode((500,400))?

Comment: @Haz [pygameHelloWorld.py](http://inventwithpython.com/pygameHelloWorld.py), this script is from book *Invent you own computer games with Python*. So I was doing the examples.

Comment: Hmmm... the code from here: http://inventwithpython.com/chapter17.html  (which I'm assuming is what you're working with) looks correct.  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Haz I've mentioned in the question.

Comment: Like Mark suggested, I think this is probably an issue with SDL rather than with Pygame.  Have you tried running any other applications that depend on libsdl?

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` return?

Comment: @Oshawott It returns `:0`.

Comment: You say you have all the dependencies installed from that page you link, but I don't see SDL on that page. Is SDL installed?

Answer (score 28):

If you are running Pygame on a UNIX system, like a Linux server, try using a [DummyVideoDriver](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/DummyVideoDriver):

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

Comment: I no longer get the error, but the program is stuck. This is all I get in the terminal: `pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
`

Comment: This does not solve the problem, setting to "DUMMY". This routes around an underlying issue

Answer (score 6):

From similar experience the most likely problem is something is wrong with one of your SDL packages. Try running the following.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.list_modes()
```

If you get back an empty list, it's definitely because of the packages. Try reinstalling them.

*Possibly related:*

- [SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841908/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device)
- [SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709719/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Comment: 1. I get `pygame.error: video system not initialized`. 2. And I get `sdl.c:1:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory` when compiling. The second one is not the one I expected because I installed SDL\* by package manager, so no chance of misconfiguration.

Comment: @SantoshKumar thats a simple error, is the include directory in your path?

Comment: I added but nothing happened.

Comment: When you installed SDL by package manager, did you install v1.2 or v2.x?

Comment: The video system not being initialized is just because you never called pygame.display.init(). If your problem is like mine, however, which it probably isn't because I am doing this in an Ubuntu virtual box, you will actually get a non-empty list from this command.

Comment: @someone-or-other `pygame.init()` should do this automatically similar to SDL's `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)`.

Comment: It worked after I called pygame.display.init() though, so maybe try it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem might only affect Windows XP. Try adding one of these to your code:

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']='windib'
```

or

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']='windlib'
```

Good luck.

Comment: Do you have the proper GPU drivers installed?  If you're running a desktop you need to install the drivers that came with on its CD not just the ones Windows suggest.  That's all I can suggest.

Comment: Its an *oooold* CRT monitor, and I don't think any driver came with this monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess - is the DISPLAY environment variable set and/or required by the library, and not available?  This could be the case if you're ssh-ing into the Linux machine you're running this on without providing the -X option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can solve the problem using x11.

Verify that your SDL was built with x11 support, otherwise build it yourself only after that you added some libraries in this way:

```
sudo apt install xorg-dev libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Maybe *xorg-dev* already installs *libx11-dev*

Build SDL from source and enjoy

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Added details to my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the three commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while trying to render an OpenAI gym in a jupyter notebook. Following fushan's answer got it to stop erroring, but it only rendered a black image. Looking at https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQUsingSDL, I figured out that I could use `directfb` as the renderer. The code ended up being:

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "directfb"
```