# pygame: doesn't open window / 'pygame.error: No available video device'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame

I am currently trying to make pygame run on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. After getting the error 'No available video device' I added the following lines of code:

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'dummy'
```

Now the error message is gone, but the window still does not pop up...
I am using python 3.8.3 and pygame 2.0.0.dev10.

Does somebody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Because setting `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` to `"dummy"` it won't actually render anything. [As stated at the bottom of the wiki](https://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars):

> If you need an event queue but don't want a real window, try putenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy") before you call SDL_SetVideoMode. I find this useful in apps that use SDL facilities, but don't need a real video output device.

Since you are on Linux, you will need to set the value of `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` to one of the Linux video drivers which can be found [here](https://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars).

If it still doesn't work, you may need to re-install your video drivers or [something is wrong with one of your SDL packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933493/pygame-error-no-available-video-device) and they may need to be re-installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried reinstalling all the packages, which also didn't do anything.
Fixed the problem by adding:

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ': 0.0'