# Amazon Ec2 Linux : SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

I am trying to run android emulator on Amazon EC2 linux,

```
Linux ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx 3.2.30-49.59.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 3 19:54:33 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But it gives me "SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device " error. As I donnot hv apt-get, I tried the approaches on [SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841908/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device) without luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Amazon Linux and It does not support anything that needs Graphical UI. Even its Package repository does not have packages for any GUI stuff.

Whatever you are doing, try it with RHEL/Ubuntu/CenOS/Fedora AMIs which support running GUI.