# SDL and portability issue

Tags: sdl

I compiled simple program on my i386 laptop. Then i try to execute it on amd64 PC and it starting, but then 
`SDL_Init Error: No available video device` 
OS: debian 7.6.0 on both computers.

I installed libc6:i386, it didn't help

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841908/sdl-init-failure-reason-is-no-available-video-device)

Comment: tried to install all the packages offered there. Some of them have already been removed, the installation of the rest did not help